# Compare tensors with different dimensions

Tags: tensorflow

I have two tensors with different dimensions. Say tensor `A` with dimension `(1,3)` and tensor `B` with dimension `(1, 5)`.

```
A = [a1, a2, a3]
B = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]
```

There is a known grouping between these values. For example, `b1` and `b2` correspond to `a1`, `b3` corresponds to `a2`, and `b4` and `b5` correspond to `a3`. I want to calculate the difference between these tensors.
So I want tensor `C` as:

```
C = [b1-a1, b2-a1, b3-a2, b4-a3, b5-a3]
```

In order to do this I have to convert `A` to:

```
A = [a1, a1, a2, a3, a3]
```

Then I can calculate `C`.

Is there a way to create a new tensor by duplicating the values of a given tensor by given number of times?
For example I can provide array/tensor `[2, 1, 2]` indicating how many times each element in `A` should be duplicated.

I tried using `tf.tile` but it operates at dimension level and cannot duplicate values of a tensor.

`tf.map_fn` seems to be a good way to do modifications to values in a tensor. But I was not able to get it working for above scenario.

I tried something like this:

```
k=(tf.constant([1,2]), tf.constant([2,3]))
z=tf.map_fn(lambda x: [code here to duplicate elements in x[0] by x[1] times], k, dtype=tf.int32)
```

But was not able to figure out `[code here to duplicate elements in x[0] by x[1] times]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `tf.map_fn`. Vectorization can be achieved by combining `tf.sequence_mask` and `tf.boolean_mask`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant([1,2,3])
indic = tf.constant([2,1,2])

max_length = tf.reduce_max(indic,axis=0)
# 2
new_A = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(A,1),[1,max_length])
# [[1 1]
#  [2 2]
#  [3 3]]
mask = tf.sequence_mask(indic,max_length)
# [[ True  True]
#  [ True False]
#  [ True  True]]
result = tf.boolean_mask(new_A,mask)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

[1 1 2 3 3]
```